# MUI React Drawer white screen after click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I am trying to do this 1:1: https://codesandbox.io/s/mxz2m3?file=/demo.js, the buttons are visible, but after clicking there is a white screen.

Comment: In you sandbox code it's working ok, can't replicate the issue with the white screen no matter which button I click. Can you please be more specific? Thanks

Comment: this is not my sandbox, it's the demo from mui.com. i did "npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled" and "npm install @mui/icons-material". is anything other needed to run drawer? thank you akis.

Comment: If you are not getting any errors in your editor or console of anything missing then I would assume you have everything you need, but probably there is something else, (maybe in your css?) that is causing the issue. Can you create a sandbox so we can have a look and be able to find the issue and provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know sample code that we use for deleting background i send my drawer sample code

```
<Drawer
                    anchor={"bottom"}
                    open={resultOpen}
                    PaperProps={{square: false, style: {backgroundColor: "transparent"}}}
                    onClose={() => setResultOpen(!resultOpen)}>
                    <LayoutDrawer>
.....
```